# How to use Response.Redirect from sub folder to root in ASP.NET, Prevent user from viewing directory listing

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, directory-listing

I have two pages in my root directory
1. Default.aspx (login page)
2. Home.aspx

and also one folder Attachments where i store the attachment files, from Home.aspx user can download the attachments. In order to prevent user from viewing Directory listing i add one more aspx page in this directory.
1. Root/Attachments/Default.aspx

now i want to Redirect the user to login page (Root/Default.aspx) from Root/Attachments/Default.aspx.

How this could be done.

Comment: Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do:

- `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")`
- [disable directory browsing in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx) also make sure that Default.aspx is a default document.

If you do the second option, you could then change your redirect to `Response.Redirect("~/")`.